# Remove leading zero from a calculator in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple calculator with jQuery. The idea is the display is initially set to zero when onload and also when the clear button is clicked. When I click any button, the number zero should be replaced with numbers or operator based on what I've clicked. Problem is the number zero is leading next to other numbers and it shouldn't be there unless I clicked decimal button.

I've tried some approaches like when any button is clicked (e.g. 7, +, etc.), replace number zero on display with corresponding button values. Sadly, doing this will either return correct values but won't add further numbers and operators, or simply stops functioning all together.

Is there a way to bypass this issue? Any guidance and tips are greatly appreciated.

```js
// Set initial display to zero
$("#display").val(0);

// User inputs the numbers and operators
function number(value) {
  // Remove leading zero if any button is clicked
  //  $("#display").val(''); <-- this will clear 0 but will prevent calculator from functioning normally
  document.form.result.value += value;
}

// Clear the display and set display to zero
function cle(value) {
  document.form.result.value = 0;
}

// Calculate the numbers
function evalua() {
  document.form.result.value = eval(
    document.form.result.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="result" readonly></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="7" type="button">7</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="8" type="button">8</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="9" type="button">9</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="+" type="button">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="4" type="button">4</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="5" type="button">5</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="6" type="button">6</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="-" type="button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="1" type="button">1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="2" type="button">2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="3" type="button">3</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="*" type="button">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="0" type="button">0</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="." type="button">.</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="number(value)" value="/" type="button">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="cle(value)" value="" type="button">AC</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="evalua()" type="button">=</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `</input>` ? No no `<input>` is a *viod* Element and does not needs a closing tag.

Comment: What you are doing here is building a string (containing the sum) which makes it pretty unpleasant to check what currently exists. Since you only use `+-*/`, maybe consider building an array of numbers/operators e.g. `[1,'+',20]`, that way you can easily see the last whole number and modify it (and also evaluate the sum [without using `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the id of the input. For zero, you can check in the following way

```js
// Set initial display to zero
$("#display").val(0);

// User inputs the numbers and operators
function number(value) {
  // Remove leading zero if any button is clicked
  //  $("#display").val(''); <-- this will clear 0 but will prevent calculator from functioning normally
  // if the display has only a 0 and user trying to add more 0 then just return
  if (value == '0' && $("#display").val() == '0') return
  // if the value is not 0 and the display is only 0, then change it to the value
  if (value != '0' && $("#display").val() == '0') {
    $("#display").val(value)
    return
  }
  document.form.result.value += value;
}

// Clear the display and set display to zero
function cle(value) {
  document.form.result.value = 0;
}

// Calculate the numbers
function evalua() {
  document.form.result.value = eval(
    document.form.result.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="display" name="result" readonly></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="7" type="button">7</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="8" type="button">8</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="9" type="button">9</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="+" type="button">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="4" type="button">4</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="5" type="button">5</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="6" type="button">6</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="-" type="button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="1" type="button">1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="2" type="button">2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="3" type="button">3</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="*" type="button">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="0" type="button">0</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="." type="button">.</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="number(value)" value="/" type="button">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="cle(value)" value="" type="button">AC</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="evalua()" type="button">=</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: That only works for the first thing entered. You can still have `1+000001`

Comment: Yes, you can have that kind input with the above solution. I showed a way to solve it with example. I'm not going to complete the assignment with all the possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

0.05 will become .05 ?

```js
// Set initial display to zero
$("#display").val(0);

// User inputs the numbers and operators
function number(value) {
  // Remove leading zero if any button is clicked
  if(value - 0 % 1 == 0)
    value -= 0;
  if(document.form.result.value.split('0').join('') == '')
    document.form.result.value = '';
  if(document.form.result.value.indexOf('.') > 0 && value == '.')
    value = '';
  document.form.result.value += value;
}

// Clear the display and set display to zero
function cle(value) {
  document.form.result.value = 0;
}

// Calculate the numbers
function evalua() {
  document.form.result.value = eval(
    document.form.result.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="result" value="0" readonly></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="7" type="button">7</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="8" type="button">8</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="9" type="button">9</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="+" type="button">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="4" type="button">4</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="5" type="button">5</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="6" type="button">6</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="-" type="button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="1" type="button">1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="2" type="button">2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="3" type="button">3</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="*" type="button">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="0" type="button">0</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="." type="button">.</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="number(value)" value="/" type="button">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="cle(value)" value="" type="button">AC</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="evalua()" type="button">=</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You should use `null`.

```js
// Set initial display to zero
$("#display").val(0);

// User inputs the numbers and operators
function number(value) {
  // Remove leading zero if any button is clicked
  //  $("#display").val(''); <-- this will clear 0 but will prevent calculator from functioning normally
  if (value == "." && !$('input[name="result"]').val()) {
    value = "0."
  }
  
  document.form.result.value += value;
}

// Clear the display and set display to zero
function cle(value) {
  document.form.result.value = null;
}

// Calculate the numbers
function evalua() {
  document.form.result.value = eval(
    document.form.result.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="result" readonly></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="7" type="button">7</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="8" type="button">8</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="9" type="button">9</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="+" type="button">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="4" type="button">4</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="5" type="button">5</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="6" type="button">6</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="-" type="button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="1" type="button">1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="2" type="button">2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="3" type="button">3</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="*" type="button">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="0" type="button">0</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="number(value)" value="." type="button">.</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="number(value)" value="/" type="button">/</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="cle(value)" value="" type="button">AC</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="evalua()" type="button">=</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```